# Does this inverter gate need a decoupling capacitor?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, inverter

I found that most data sheets show that ICs need a decoupling capacitor.

Does the SN74LVC1G04 inverter need one also? [The datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g04.pdf) does not seem to show one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Section 11 of the data sheet discusses appropriate power supply capacitor selection and layout. 0.1 microfarad as close to the power pin as possible, pretty standard. Even if the data sheet didn't state that a power supply bypass capacitor was required, the best practice is to include one, unless specifically forbidden. The gate will try to switch from a LOW output condition to a HIGH output as quickly as possible, drawing additional current from the supply which, given the inevitable trace resistance and inductance, cannot be provided instantaneously. Adding a small capacitor very close to the power pins acts as a small local reserve of energy to prevent excessive voltage sag on the power inputs which could cause undesirable behavior.